# "placeholder” attribute using knockout - JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, knockout.js

I would like to use placeholder attribute using `data-bind` but I have a error message([object object]) . Please let me know how can I use it.

**html:**

```
input id="comments" class="form-control" 
data-bind="attr: { placeholder: { locale: 'placeholder.comments', auth: false } }"
```

**json:**

```
"placeholder": {
    "comments": "Tell us..."
}
```

Comment: you could store you JSON 'comments' in a ko.observable() called 'comment' and add it like this, 
input id="comments" class="form-control" data-bind="attr: { placeholder: comment }"

Comment: I know I can store in js file but I would like to call json text because it's not only one data. Thank you.

Comment: It works in text field but not in placeholder section.  input id="comments" class="form-control" data-bind=" locale: 'placeholder.comments'"

Comment: Is *data-bind=" **locale**: 'placeholder.comments'"* a custom bindingHandler?

Comment: Yes, it is a custom bindingHandler.

Comment: Can you post it please. You can probably set the **placeholder** attribute that way.

Comment: http://i18next.com/pages/sample.html

Comment: Definitely the way to go is to create a custom binding which preprocess your parameters. Have a look at the i18next implementations, someone provided an [angular directive](https://gist.github.com/archer96/5239617) for doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The placeholder attribute should be a string (ko.observable), not an object.

```
<input data-bind="attr:{placeholder:hintText}" />
```

Simple example:
http://jsfiddle.net/xtdL7om1/

Answer (score 0):

You can create an bindingHandlers like this :

```
ko.bindingHandlers.placeholder = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var observable = valueAccessor();
        ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { attr: { placeholder: observable } });
    }
};
```

and u have to use like this in HTML

```
<input id="test" data-bind="placeholder: yourPlaceHorder, textInput: yourValueInput" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input widgetLocaleText: {value:'nameOnCardPlaceholder', attr:'placeholder'},
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.